# remove vertices in blender

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm a beginner and I have a problem with merging vertices or removing them, I cant find remove by distance or I can't remove them with merge by distance.

It shows `0 vertices removed`, if i increase the merge distance its happening like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can join the two loops with "Bridge Edge Loops" then remove one of them with "Dissolve Edges".

Comment: NO I cant find the solution for the problem in this way .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, now, you can edit multiple objects simultaneously, you can't merge vertices between them. In this case, I suspect you will have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> join the *objects* in Object Mode, before merging vertices in what would then be a single mesh.

Comment: BTW, a more direct way to do this might be to create the hemisphere, and then EZ extrude the edges on the equator downwards

Comment: yeah tht would be easy . thanks dude  ;-)

Comment: Good eye, I didn't notice these were two different objects :).